# by default MySQL should connect to aws rds instead of localhost?

Tags: mysql, email, server, postfix-mta, dovecot

I want to Set Up an Email Server With Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL. I followed all the steps which were mentioned in this documentation

https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/

but somehow I ended up with this error

DATABASE ERROR: CONNECTION FAILED!
Unable to connect to the database!
Please contact your server administrator.

please let me know if i am missing anything

Comment: I don't want to refer to local MySQL instead point to aws rds

Comment: How the heck will we know if you’re missing anything without verifying each step twice? 

Comment: while setting up MySQL Database for Your Postfix Email Server I should follow sudo mysql_secure_installation or instead I am referring to mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf to point my was rds instance, is there a place in Amazon Linux or Ubuntu I need to modify to point was rds instead of local host